# Java, operations with an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I want to store the player's data and the field's data in two arrays of object. The problem is I need to work with these in a different classes. In the class where I originally created its not a problem but when I try to call it in another class it throws "`board[i]` cannot be resolved to a variable".

The code I am writing is kind of similar to this:

```
class Field {
    int something;
    int another;

    public void setMethod(int something){
        this.something = something;
    } 

    //etc. 
}
```

```
class Board {
public static Field[] board = new Field[60];

    public void BoardFiller(){
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
            board[i] = new Field(/*construct*/);
            //etc.
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Gameplay {
    public boolean Attackable() {
        boolean atk = false;

        //stuff
        int something = board[i].getMethod();
        //more stuff
        return atk;
    }
}
```

And so on. I have to use the Field data to check if it's reachable, use it in the turns, in the I/O part.
The problem is the same with the Player data.

Comment: You have to reference your static variable via the class it is defined in. In other words: `Board.board[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Remove the `static` modifier from the `board` variable

Step 2: Add a `public Board board = new Board();` field to the `Gameplay` class

Step 3: Use `board.board[...]` to access the fields in the `Gameplay` class

Comment: "Step 0" add a method to GamePlay, as is it's invalid

Comment: k this method works too. i just asked him to make the filed class static too.
bt this way is right since he is calling methods from field class

Answer (score 0):

Just like you created a field object using new Field() you need to create a board object in your gameplay class to be able to use the methods in there.

```
Board myBoard = new Board();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the `board` variable in the scope of the `Attackable` method or the `Gameplay` class. In order to get access to the `board` variable, you have to access it by doing `Field.Board.board`. instead of just `board`.

Answer (score 0):

In GamePlay class you have to loop over the board. Something like for(Field f : new Board().board) //do something

Answer (score 0):

the code is totally wrong it wont even compile you are not allowed to create 
static array of outer class within the inner class

> An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly
>   declared static. Inner classes may not declare static initializers
>   or member interfaces. Inner classes may not declare static
>   members, unless they are compile-time constant fields

you should get a compile error you can fix this by making your field class static.